# How can i do a redirect with 404 as status code in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, http-status-code-404, http-status-code

> We have moved our website to a new domain and our SEO department want to have some redirect from the old urls to the new urls with 404 status code. I dont know if it is possible and want to collect some opinions from the community

My question: i want to try to configure a redirect from a internal url to a external URL with 404 as status code in Nginx. I have tried with `rewrite` and `return`. But it looks like that it's imposible.

- `rewrite` can only return 301 or 302 as status code.
- `return` can't do any redirect with 404.
- I have tried with `rewrite last` and `return 404`. But it didn't work, because i want to redirect to external URL.

Anyone has some idea?

Comment: You can’t redirect with 404. You could use JavaScript (or meta tag) to make browser to navigate to another page after receiving 404 page.

Comment: Thank you, i need it for a SEO requirement. Because of that is a client redirect with JS not useful for me.

Comment: SEO requirements can’t change how HTTP protocol works

Comment: What is your SEO requirement? There may be an actually possible way to achieve it.

Comment: @MikeScott: We have moved our website to a new domain and our SEO department want to have some redirect from the old urls to the new urls with 404 status code. I dont know if it is possible and want to collect some ideas from the community

Comment: @AlexeyTen: please see my comment above...

Comment: So what's wrong with JS/Metatag solution? They'll have 404 and eventually user will be redirected to any page you want.

Comment: Still, I can't understand why would anyone want 404 *and* redirect. If you know new location of an old url, just redirect user there. No need for 404.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Do you mind redirect with JS? You know, SEO is for search engine and some SE can't work with JS correctly. Other way: we want, that it works from the server side.

Comment: @AlexeyTen: i said exactly the same to our SEO department but still want to collect more opinions about this topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ye canna change the laws of physics.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. 404 isn’t a redirect status code, it’s an error status code, and so web browsers that receive it will treat it as an error rather than a redirect. If you want to say that the page isn’t there any more and send the browser to find it somewhere else, that’s what the 301 code is for.

Comment: Yes i know, but are there some tricks to do it? Something like error_page?

Answer (score 1):

A 404 can be done only internally it can't be done for an external URL. You can only direct it but not with a 404. A 404 means that it's not there or dosen't exists.

If both servers or urls belongs to you, you can redirect to a php page with a php header of 404 and a refresh html meta that would redirect to the new URL. But this is not the right way to redirect

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the HTTP status code of an external page.

However, if what you want to achieve is *displaying* external page's content with 404 status on your site, this is totally possible. You can use `proxy_pass`.

But it gets more tricky if the remote location emits `200`. Two locations would be needed:

```
location = /foo {
    error_page 404 = @ext_404;
    return 404;
}

location @ext_404 {
    proxy_pass https://bar.example.com;
    rewrite .* /lorem-ipsum break;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host bar.example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    expires 30;
}
```

As a result, when someone visits `https://your.example.com/foo`, they will actually see the contents of `https://bar.example.com/lorem-ipsum` with 404 status code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it was a requirement, that it redirects to a new URL. 
I don't want to control the status code of the new external URL. For example: If some one visits `https://your.example.com/foo`, it returns 404 for `https://your.example.com/foo` and do a redirect to `https://new.example2.com/foo`. So the new URL `https://new.example2.com/foo` can have a new status code, musst not be 404.

Comment: Your requirement would be more clear if you can answer: what is the final URL to be shown in the browser address bar? your site's URL displaying external contents, or an external URL with external contents?

Comment: It should be **an external URL with external contents**

Comment: Well, then you can't do anything about it as you are not in control of the external server.

Comment: May be u understood it false. I don't want to do anything with the external server. I want to change set a status code 404 for the url of my server and return a redirect to the new server. Something like that `rewrite mysite.com newsite.com [404]`

Comment: It is simply impossible by HTTP specification. There is no 404 + redirect URL. No browser supports this scenario. You can only supply redirect URL with 301 and 302.

Comment: Ok. I hear about this. But want to try to find a way to do it. Thank you very much!