# how to make a redirect conditional on nginx conf

Tags: linux, nginx, redirect, conditional

I should make a conditional rediction in nginx.
I would like to do something like that.

$http_code = code from curl commande

if ( $http_code = 200 ){

"redirection to server 1"

}

else {

"redirection to server 2"

}

So can someone help me to find a way to do it, or give me example of nginx conf with condition like this.

Thanks

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1003406/how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-404-as-status-code-in-nginx the same imho can be used for any other

Comment: I have already seen this post and it does not answer my request, because i want to make a test and the rediction will be to another server depending to result

Comment: location = /foo { error_page 404 = @ext_404; }

location @ext_404 {
    proxy_pass https://bar.example.com;

it does not answer it? it DOES

Comment: You can join me on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126791/thechat and we will discuss this sutation with some words

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but i don't have enough of right to acces to the chat

Comment: now oyu should :-)

Comment: i have this message "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here" that's why i can't be on the chat

Comment: I don't think basic nginx has feature to implement such conditional processing based on results on requests to other parts. You need to use either nginx JS module or LUA module with an appropriate script to implement this logic.